# Tight calves and tingling toes when running

Tags: running, exercise

I usually run 7 km in 50 minutes roughly 3 days a week. On some days I experience tight calves
muscle which makes me stop running and even walking becomes painful. I get a this tingling toes before this occur. This is despite stretching and warm up I do before my run. Any suggestions and what should I lookout for?

Answer (score 1):

This is a WAG, but, if I were you, I'd pay close attention to your symptoms.  What you describe may be the onset of [Piriformis syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piriformis_syndrome) which is common in runners.  I would include a [piriformis stretch](https://www.google.com/search?q=piriformis+stretch&rlz=1C1CHMO_enUS470US470&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=Fd5HU6y4KdSysQSw6IDwCA&sqi=2&ved=0CCUQsAQ&biw=1920&bih=955) in your routine if you are not already doing it.

Comment: not true!   Check out where your pisiformis is!  It's in your backside not your calves

Comment: @Tracyat2bactive The location of the "piriformis" in the buttock does not preclude it from causing symptoms in the lower extremities.  In fact, this syndrome is common for runners.  And, as someone who was surgically treated for nerve impingement, I can attest to the fact that calf involvement, numbness and tingling in the toes is common.

Comment: @rrirower  I am aware that the piriformis crosses the sciatic nerve.  I have heard of it causing tightness in the hamstring and sciatica.  I had not heard of this problem with the calves.  I apologise for my comment, but it didn't appear to make any sense.  Thanks for explanation

Comment: However,I will give a try to this piriformis stretch which looks good.

Answer (score 0):

sorry this is so brief but i need to workout but dont want anyone to suffer  :
make sure it is not simply a trigger point
essentially a ball on your muscle you can deep massage with a ball
check out the trigger point therapy workbook 
it might be a trigger point on the piriformis
in which case dont stretch

will edit later
if anyone can help please edit for me